# DPDK: All TX and RX packets dropped with RPi-CM4 + Intel-i210-NIC

Tags: raspberry-pi, ethernet, dpdk, nic

Unable to send packets using `testpmd` or `pktgen` on my Raspberry Pi CM4 with an Intel i210 NIC, although the same setup works fine on a x86 Dell station with the same NIC.

Could this issue be due to DPDK's compatibility on ARM or RPi, or I have done something wrong?

### Environment:

```
host:
    Raspberry Pi CM4 + standard IO board

NIC:
    I tried both NIC following
    Intel i210-GE-1T-X1 (1Gb)
    Intel i210-X1-V2 (10Gb)

Kernel:
    I tried both linux-raspi 5.4 & linux-raspi 5.15

DPDK:
    dpdk-23.07
    I tried both vfio_pic (no-iommu) & uio_pci_generic driver
```

### Test results:

Run testpmd:

`./dpdk-testpmd -- -i`

```
EAL: Detected CPU lcores: 4
EAL: Detected NUMA nodes: 1
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: Using IOMMU type 8 (No-IOMMU)
EAL: Probe PCI driver: net_e1000_igb (8086:1533) device: 0000:01:00.0 (socket -1)
TELEMETRY: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created
Interactive-mode selected
Warning: NUMA should be configured manually by using --port-numa-config and --ring-numa-config parameters along with --numa.
testpmd: create a new mbuf pool <mb_pool_0>: n=171456, size=2176, socket=0
testpmd: preferred mempool ops selected: ring_mp_mc

Warning! port-topology=paired and odd forward ports number, the last port will pair with itself.

Configuring Port 0 (socket 0)
Port 0: 98:B7:85:00:89:4D
Checking link statuses...
Done
testpmd> 
Port 0: link state change event
```

Start TX-only forward mode

```
set fwd txonly
start <--- In this step, I can see the RJ45 lights on, but no blink. 
stop
```

```
txonly packet forwarding - ports=1 - cores=1 - streams=1 - NUMA support enabled, MP allocation mode: native
Logical Core 1 (socket 0) forwards packets on 1 streams:
  RX P=0/Q=0 (socket 0) -> TX P=0/Q=0 (socket 0) peer=02:00:00:00:00:00

  txonly packet forwarding packets/burst=32
  packet len=64 - nb packet segments=1
  nb forwarding cores=1 - nb forwarding ports=1
  port 0: RX queue number: 1 Tx queue number: 1
    Rx offloads=0x0 Tx offloads=0x0
    RX queue: 0
      RX desc=512 - RX free threshold=32
      RX threshold registers: pthresh=0 hthresh=0  wthresh=0
      RX Offloads=0x0
    TX queue: 0
      TX desc=512 - TX free threshold=0
      TX threshold registers: pthresh=8 hthresh=1  wthresh=16
      TX offloads=0x0 - TX RS bit threshold=0
testpmd> stop
Telling cores to stop...
Waiting for lcores to finish...

  ---------------------- Forward statistics for port 0  ----------------------
  RX-packets: 0              RX-dropped: 0             RX-total: 0
  TX-packets: 0              TX-dropped: 55054369      TX-total: 55054369
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

  +++++++++++++++ Accumulated forward statistics for all ports+++++++++++++++
  RX-packets: 0              RX-dropped: 0             RX-total: 0
  TX-packets: 0              TX-dropped: 55054369      TX-total: 55054369
  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Check port information:

`show port info 0`

```
********************* Infos for port 0  *********************
MAC address: 98:B7:85:00:89:4D
Device name: 0000:01:00.0
Driver name: net_e1000_igb
Firmware-version: 3.16, 0x800004ff, 1.304.0
Connect to socket: 0
memory allocation on the socket: 0
Link status: up
Link speed: 1 Gbps
Link duplex: full-duplex
Autoneg status: On
MTU: 1500
Promiscuous mode: enabled
Allmulticast mode: disabled
Maximum number of MAC addresses: 16
Maximum number of MAC addresses of hash filtering: 0
VLAN offload: 
  strip off, filter off, extend off, qinq strip off
Hash key size in bytes: 40
Redirection table size: 128
Supported RSS offload flow types:
  ipv4  ipv4-tcp  ipv4-udp  ipv6  ipv6-tcp  ipv6-udp  ipv6-ex
  ipv6-tcp-ex  ipv6-udp-ex
Minimum size of RX buffer: 256
Maximum configurable length of RX packet: 16383
Maximum configurable size of LRO aggregated packet: 0
Current number of RX queues: 1
Max possible RX queues: 4
Max possible number of RXDs per queue: 4096
Min possible number of RXDs per queue: 32
RXDs number alignment: 8
Current number of TX queues: 1
Max possible TX queues: 4
Max possible number of TXDs per queue: 4096
Min possible number of TXDs per queue: 32
TXDs number alignment: 8
Max segment number per packet: 255
Max segment number per MTU/TSO: 255
Device capabilities: 0x0( )
Device error handling mode: none
Device private info:
  none
```

Check Linux VFIO modules:

`lsmod`

```
    vfio_pci               16384  0
    vfio_pci_core          77824  1 vfio_pci
    vfio_virqfd            16384  1 vfio_pci_core
    vfio_iommu_type1       49152  0
    vfio                   45056  2 vfio_pci_core,vfio_iommu_type1
```

Check device bind:

`dpdk-devbind.py -s`

```
    Network devices using DPDK-compatible driver
    ============================================
    0000:01:00.0 'I210 Gigabit Network Connection 1533' drv=vfio-pci unused=igb
```

Kernel logs:

```
[    0.565384] pci 0000:01:00.0: [8086:1533] type 00 class 0x020000
[    0.565449] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0x00000000-0x000fffff]
[    0.565521] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x1c: [mem 0x00000000-0x00003fff]
[    0.565590] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x30: [mem 0x00000000-0x000fffff pref]
[    0.565881] pci 0000:01:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.581511] pci_bus 0000:01: busn_res: [bus 01-ff] end is updated to 01
[    0.581600] pci 0000:00:00.0: BAR 14: assigned [mem 0x600000000-0x6002fffff]
[    0.581628] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0x600000000-0x6000fffff]
[    0.581655] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 6: assigned [mem 0x600100000-0x6001fffff pref]
[    0.581673] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 3: assigned [mem 0x600200000-0x600203fff]
```

Kernel logs when I start testpmd:

```
[   54.287336] vfio_pci: unknown parameter 'enable_unsafe_noiommu_mode' ignored
[   82.338189] vfio-pci 0000:01:00.0: Adding to iommu group 0
[   82.338210] vfio-pci 0000:01:00.0: Adding kernel taint for vfio-noiommu group on device
[  121.902266] audit: type=1326 audit(1696353003.891:65): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=2 subj=snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software pid=1979 comm="pool-org.gnome." exe="/snap/snap-store/639/usr/bin/snap-store" sig=0 arch=c00000b7 syscall=55 compat=0 ip=0xffff9e093ee8 code=0x50000
[  126.390013] vfio-pci 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[  126.498474] vfio-pci 0000:01:00.0: vfio-noiommu device opened by user (dpdk-testpmd:3057)
[  215.791550] vfio-pci 0000:01:00.0: vfio-noiommu device opened by user (pktgen:3938)
[ 4084.938242] vfio-pci 0000:01:00.0: timed out waiting for pending transaction; performing function level reset anyway
[ 5253.671006] vfio-pci 0000:01:00.0: vfio-noiommu device opened by user (dpdk-testpmd:5719)
[ 5532.162849] vfio-pci 0000:01:00.0: vfio-noiommu device opened by user (dpdk-testpmd:5754)
[ 5541.958851] vfio-pci 0000:01:00.0: vfio-noiommu device opened by user (dpdk-testpmd:5765)
[ 5647.800353] vfio-pci 0000:01:00.0: vfio-noiommu device opened by user (dpdk-testpmd:5796)
[ 5709.481186] vfio-pci 0000:01:00.0: vfio-noiommu device opened by user (dpdk-testpmd:5819)
[ 5744.089540] vfio-pci 0000:01:00.0: vfio-noiommu device opened by user (dpdk-testpmd:5830)
```

Same results with using `uio_pci_generic` driver.

I also tried use rx_only, all receving packets are also dropped.

I have tested RPi-CM4 + i210 can work well based on Linux API.

Let me know if there is any other information I can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Update on this, the issue shown above was due to missing root privileges. The error I meant to share is:

```
$ sudo dpdk-testpmd -- -i
EAL: Detected CPU lcores: 4
EAL: Detected NUMA nodes: 1
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: Cannot open directory /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages to read system hugepage info
EAL: FATAL: Cannot get hugepage information.
EAL: Cannot get hugepage information.
EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
  Cause: Cannot init EAL: Permission denied
```